# error: database is locked in sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c

//create database here

```
   -(void) createDataBase
   {
           docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

            fullPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.sqlite"];
           sqlite3_open([fullPath UTF8String], &dbForEmf);
    }

    // create table

    -(void) createTable
    {    
            if (sqlite3_open([fullPath UTF8String], &dbForE) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                    const char* createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EEE(E_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL, E_NAME TEXT,E_READING TEXT,E_DATE TEXT,E_SIZE TEXT,E_LABLE TEXT)";

                    int errorCode = sqlite3_prepare(dbForE, createQuery, -1, &prepareStmt, NULL);

                    if (errorCode == 0) {
                        sqlite3_step(prepareStmt);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    sqlite3_finalize(prepareStmt);
                    sqlite3_close(dbForE);
            }
          else
           {
               NSLog(@"data base not Open");
           }
        }
    // insert data here

        -(void) insertData
        {
            if (sqlite3_open([fullPath UTF8String], &dbForE)==SQLITE_OK)
            {    
                NSString *insertSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO EEE(E_NAME,E_READING,E_DATE,E_SIZE,E_LABLE) VALUES('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",_referenceObject.lastFilePath,_referenceObject.fileString,_referenceObject.dateString,_referenceObject.fileSizeString,_referenceObject.titleOfButtonString];               
                const char *insert_stmt=[insertSql UTF8String];

                sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbForE,insert_stmt,-1,&prepareStmt,NULL);
                sqlite3_reset(prepareStmt);
                if (sqlite3_step(prepareStmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"inserted the values in table");

                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@" not inserted the values in table");
                    NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dbForE));
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(prepareStmt);
                sqlite3_close(dbForE);
            }


        }
```

hai data is insert on first viewController   when ever i goto second viewController and come back to first viewController the data is  not inserted  error displays database is locked...

Comment: hi, i Like Your Photos,may be you leave the database open in another ViewController

Comment: i open another ViewController and close it there

Comment: &dbForEmf & &dbForE thease two db?

Comment: Sorry copy past problem dbForE only one db where ever dbForEmf treat has dbForE..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288551/sqlite3-database-is-getting-locked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974781/database-is-locked-in-sqlite-in-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442541/sqlite-database-locked-in-some-case-while-inserting-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929104/sqlite3-ios-database-is-locked

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6860411/656600

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database is locked in Sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658565/database-is-locked-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

check if you have leave the database open in second ViewController or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

in createDataBase you have opened your database and it was not closed and you again tried to open this hence your database get locked first you should close database in createdatabase function.

Comment: Data Base locked problem only occur when you forgot to close the database Please check your code this is the only reason by which you are getting this problem